# Google Sheets - Concatenate NOW-1, slash, and NOW+120

Tags: date, google-sheets, formulas

In Google Sheets, I need to create a date in the following format:

> 2016-06-15T12:00-0800/2016-10-16T12:00-0800

(Yesterday's date / today's date + 120 days)

Using `=NOW()-1`, I get yesterday's date.

Using Format - Date - More - `Year(1930)-Month(05)-Day(01)T:Hour(01):00-0800`, I get the proper format for the 1st part of the date range (`2016-06-15T12:00-0800`).

Repeating the same process with `=NOW()+120`.

Got the 2nd part of the date range (`2016-10-16T12:00-0800`).

PROBLEM: Trying to `=CONCATENATE(A2,"/",B2)`, results in this:

> 42901.6965777315/43022.6965777315

...and no matter what I do - change the format, try to use `=CONCATENATE(=TEXT(A2),"/",=TEXT(B2))`, or other tricks I know, I either get a blank cell, an error message, or an even worse mess.

All I want is to combine 2 date cells into 1, with a slash in between. How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try join instead of concatenate:

```
=join("/",A1,B1)
```

Comment: This will not return the expected result for cells containing dates.

Comment: @Rubén It seems to work in my test. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FYEqI74KqlxG637xL21VJ12aDtCbVksIp_4bak-ynA4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: That's weird that JOIN works differently than CONCAT and CONCATENATE, etc. If your answer is edited let me know to revert my negative vote. (by the way, I'm sorry for assuming that JOIN will work the same way as the other functions)

Comment: Worked!
A1 contains "2017-06-16T19:00-0800"
B1 contains "2017-10-15T19:00-0800"
C1 contains "2017-06-16T19:00-0800/2017-10-15T19:00-0800"

THANK YOU!

Comment: So, both answers given work; I chose this one as the answer, since it's a lot simpler. But the answer provided by "pnuts" will work in a single cell, whereas this requires 3 cells.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

```
=text(now()-1,"yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm")&"-0800/"&text(now()+120,"yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm")&"-0800"
```

Comment: That works - but Ed Nelson provided a much simpler solution below, so I'm marking his post as the answer. Thank you anyway, I'm sure this will come in handy too - especially if I'm in a situation where this has to be done in a **single** cell, as opposed to 3 cells.

Answer (score 0):

TEXT with only a date as argument returns the serial number corresponding to that date,

First you should confer the result of you formulas that involves NOW to a formatted text by using TEXT with the second argument. Then you could concatenate the result of that.

The above be donde on a single formula but you maybe should start by doing each step on separate cells in order to make it easy to check the result of each part.